# Parse Markdown with Markdig to get parts by type

Tags: c#, markdown, asp.net-core-3.1

In an old project, we were using [Microsoft.Toolkit.Parsers.Markdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.parsers.markdown.markdowndocument?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0) to parse Markdown content.

For example, we use that library to get the list of headings in a MD block, like this:

```cs
void Main()
{

    string md = @"
# h1
## h2

Some content.

## h2 bis

some other content
    ";

    var headings = GetHeadings(md);
    headings.Dump();
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

private List<string> GetHeadings(string markdownContent)
{
    var document = new Microsoft.Toolkit.Parsers.Markdown.MarkdownDocument();
    document.Parse(markdownContent);

    return document.Blocks
        .Where(block => block.Type == MarkdownBlockType.Header)
        .Select(block => block.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Now, we are porting the whole project to a newer version. `Microsoft.Toolkit.Parsers.Markdown` is now deprecated, and Microsoft suggests moving to [MarkDig](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig) instead.

Is there a way to parse MD text and retrieve the different blocks as we did with the Toolkit library?

If not, which other libraries I can use to achieve the same result?

Comment: Looking at the source code, seems like you can call `Markdown.Parse(doc).Where(b => b is HeadingBlock)`

Comment: You can try it this way https://dotnetfiddle.net/AjmMNm (this is your example written with MarkDig)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [e-shcherbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8715436/e-shcherbo) in a comment to the question, this problem can be solved in this way:

```cs
var document = Markdown.Parse(markdownContent);

return document.Select(b => b as HeadingBlock)
                .Where(b => b != null)
                .Select(hb => hb.Inline.FirstChild.ToString());
```

The part I was missing was that the `MarkdownDocument` object is itself the collection of block. On the contrary, to retrieve the blocks using *Microsoft.Toolkit.Parsers.Markdown.MarkdownDocument*, you need to access the `Blocks` property.

More details [on the source code](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig/blob/master/src/Markdig/Syntax/ContainerBlock.cs).